# ajax request to form in css popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony-forms

from France ... and sorry for my english language ...

I code in symfony 3.
I have an entity "book" can have, according to the "type" attribute selected, one or more attributes (client, student, organizer and / or speaker) each mapped as an entity "user".
In my "book" form, I can select for each of the attributes related to "user" my users registered in the bdd.
I want to add a "user" by opening a popup css, loading my user form and saving it with ajax. In case of success, I recharge my list with ajax to use on my form "booking.

```js
function nouveauOrganisateur() {
    $.ajax({
        url : Routing.generate('user_new'),
        success: function(html) {
            $('#NewOrganisateur').append(
                $(html).find('form')
            );
            $('div#NewOrganisateur form button').replaceWith(
                $(
                    '<button onclick="EnregistrerClient(event)">Enregistrer</button>'
                )
            );
        }
    });
}


function EnregistrerClient( event ) {
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
    var $form = $( event.target ).closest( 'form');
    $.ajax({
        url : Routing.generate('user_new'),
        type: 'post',
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div id="UserOrganisateur" class="label">
    <strong>{{ form_label(form.Stage.organisateurs, "Organisateurs ") }}</strong>
    {{ form_errors(form.Stage.organisateurs) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.Stage.organisateurs) }}
    <button onclick="nouveauOrganisateur()">Ajouter un Nouveau client</button>
    <div id="NewOrganisateur">
        {{ form_errors(form.Stage.NewOrganisateur) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.Stage.NewOrganisateur, {'value' : false}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I validate my form "user", my page is reloaded but it is not what I want. And my user is not registered !?
I started in javascript. Can you help me?

---

From my form, I have a "select" for the type.
When the "type" is selected, thanks to FormEvents and a js script I load the rest of the form.
For example, if my "type" is "training", I load the embedded entity Training form. My "training" entity contains the "organizer" attributes and "speaker", 2 multiple select which options are the "user" stored in the BDD.
In this form, I add a button to record a new "user". This button displays the registration form to use in which I replaced the submission boutton by **Ajax action button**. I just want to register my new user and recharge my list of selects ("organizer" and "speaker"), but when I click on this last boutton my page comes from where to select the "type".

---

Whith some change, I can registred my new user

```js
function nouveauOrganisateur() {
    $.ajax({
        url : Routing.generate('user_new'),
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
            $('#NewOrganisateur').append(
                $(html).find('form')
            );
            $('form[name=user] button').replaceWith(
                $(
                    '<button>Enregistrer</button>'
                )
            );
            $('form[name=user] button').on("click", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url : Routing.generate('user_new'),
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $('form[name=user]').serialize(),
                    success: function(html) {
                        console.log(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But my page is always reloaded ???

Comment: You say "my page is reloaded but it is not what I want". Could you tell us more? And are you talking about when you click on the first button?

Comment: No, I talk about the form user submit button which I change to Ajax action.

Comment: ``nouveauOrganisateur`` Try to keep your code english, if someone else has to work with your code he won't be able to understand it if he doesn't know french.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to stop the page from reloading or changing when the user clicks the button. There may be two solutions to this:

1.) The `<button>` html tag defaults to `type="submit"` which submits the form. You can avoid this by adding `type="button"`

or

2.) In the javascript function `EnregistrerClient` add a line at the top of the function `event.preventdefault();` this will stop the form from submitting.